# Loading last selected UIPickerView on startup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView to choose the PDF that should be shown. I want to save the last chosen components, so when I quit the app or restart the device, it will automatically show the last chosen PDF. I have two components, so I wanted to know how it can be done...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the selected row in `NSUserDefaults` by using `selectedRowInComponent`... 
And then while presenting the `picker` use `selectRow:inComponent:animated:`

**EDIT:**

Save like this.

```
int selectedRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:componentNumber];
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:key]); put this in didSelectRow and tell wht you are getting...

Comment: Thanks, I really hate to say it but it still doesn't do anything, it's really strange! XCode still returns 0 for NSLog

Comment: Now I dont have mac.. that's I can't help you :( ... start a new project and do a example program for NSUserdefaults and after that you can do with the picker... check out this link http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSString *numberString = [array1 objectAtIndex:[_pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSString *letterString = [array2 objectAtIndex:[_pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];

    NSString *pathComponentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stundenplan_%@%@.pdf", numberString, letterString];
    stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponentString]]]];
    NSInteger selectedRow = [_pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"picker"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:key];

}

-(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{

    [pickerView selectRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"picker"] intValue] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    self.pickerView.hidden = NO;
    cancelbtn.enabled = NO;
    cancelbar.hidden = NO;

}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.